Folium map displayed with PyQT5 flashes at every update
I am designing a map visualizer with PyQT5 and using folium. I created something but there are a few problems I couldn't solve. In this question I am only focusing on one of them and I will ask others if meanwhile if I can't solve.
Here is the issue. I have a data_provider for testing purposes. When it updates ship coordinate and heading map needs to update to keep the ship in center. But when updating I think I need recreate the map and something causes flashing. Here is the problem in a video.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gf3c2aRX7x-Tjge-gBqR8EzxuX7z6PB6/view?usp=sharing
And here is my code.
import io
import sys
import folium

from PyQt5.QtGui import QRegion
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QTimer
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class Map(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """
    Updates the map's location and heading based on parameters.
    Places a circular map inside a frame with a circular alarm mask.
    """
    triggered = False

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.map = None
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self) -> None:
        # Create layout
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Create a parent frame for the circular map
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.frame.setFixedSize(310, 310)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 5px solid black; border-radius: 155px;")
        self.frame.setGeometry(145, 10, 310, 310)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.frame)

        # Add the WebEngineView for the map inside the frame
        self.map_view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.frame)
        self.map_view.setFixedSize(300, 300)
        self.map_view.setGeometry(5, 5, 300, 300)

        # Apply a circular mask to the map view
        circular_region = QRegion(QRect(0, 0, self.map_view.width(),
                                    self.map_view.height()), QRegion.Ellipse)
        self.map_view.setMask(circular_region)

        # Create buttons and input fields
        self.control_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addLayout(self.control_layout)

        self.lat_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.lat_input.setPlaceholderText("Latitude")
        self.control_layout.addWidget(self.lat_input)

        self.lon_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.lon_input.setPlaceholderText("Longitude")
        self.control_layout.addWidget(self.lon_input)

        self.heading_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.heading_input.setPlaceholderText("Heading (degrees)")
        self.control_layout.addWidget(self.heading_input)

        self.update_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Update Location", self)
        self.update_button.clicked.connect(self.update_location)
        self.control_layout.addWidget(self.update_button)

        self.update_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Test", self)
        self.update_button.clicked.connect(self.data_provider)
        self.control_layout.addWidget(self.update_button)

        self.trigger_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Trigger Frame Color", self)
        self.trigger_button.clicked.connect(self.trigger_frame)
        self.control_layout.addWidget(self.trigger_button)

        self.example_continous_data = [
            (40.851, 29.041, 311, [(40.85851, 29.04981, 1)]),
            (40.852, 29.042, 312, [(40.85852, 29.04982, 2)]),
            (40.853, 29.043, 313, [(40.85853, 29.04983, 3)]),
            (40.854, 29.044, 314, [(40.85854, 29.04984, 4)]),
            (40.855, 29.045, 315, [(40.85855, 29.04985, 5)]),
            (40.856, 29.046, 316, [(40.85856, 29.04986, 6)]),
            (40.857, 29.047, 317, [(40.85857, 29.04987, 7)]),
            (40.858, 29.048, 318, [(40.85858, 29.04988, 8)]),
            (40.859, 29.049, 319, [(40.85859, 29.04989, 9)])
        ]
        self.data_index = 0

    def data_provider(self) -> None:
        """Update the map with the next data point every second."""
        if self.data_index < len(self.example_continous_data):
            latitude, longitude, degree, dangerous_areas = \
                self.example_continous_data[self.data_index]
            self.create_map(latitude, longitude, degree, dangerous_areas)
            self.data_index += 1
        else:
            self.data_index = 0
        self.timer2 = QTimer()
        self.timer2.timeout.connect(self.data_provider)
        self.timer2.start(1000)

    def create_map(self, latitude, longitude, heading, dangerous_areas) -> None:
        """
        Create or update a Folium map centered on the given location
          with a heading arrow.
        """
        self.map = folium.Map(
            location=[latitude, longitude],
            zoom_start=14,
            tiles="OpenStreetMap",
            attribution_control=False,
            zoom_control=True
        )
        folium.TileLayer("OpenSeaMap", name="OpenSeaMap").add_to(self.map)
        # Custom CSS for circular map and repositioned controls
        circular_css = """
        <style>
            .leaflet-top.leaflet-left {
                left: 24%; /* Adjust horizontal positioning of controls */
                top: 90%; /* Adjust vertical positioning of controls */
                transform: translate(-24%, -90%);
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1000;/*Ensure controls are visible above the map*/
            }
        </style>
        """
        # Inject the custom CSS into the map HTML
        self.map.get_root().header.add_child(folium.Element(circular_css))
        # Add a ship marker with an arrow to indicate heading
        size = 22
        arrow_icon = folium.DivIcon(html=f"""
            <div style="transform: rotate({heading}deg);\
                 font-size: {size}px; color: red;">
                &#10148;
            </div>
        """)
        marker = folium.Marker(
            location=[latitude, longitude],
            icon=arrow_icon,
            tooltip=f"{latitude}, {longitude}, {heading}°"
        )
        marker.add_to(self.map)

        # Add dangerous areas
        for lat, lon, depth in dangerous_areas:
            circle = folium.Circle(
                location=[lat, lon],
                radius=100,
                color="red",
                fill=True,
                fill_color="red",
                fill_opacity=0.5,
                tooltip=f"Depth: {depth}m"
            )
            circle.add_to(self.map)
        self.render_map()

    def render_map(self) -> None:
        # Save map to memory
        data = io.BytesIO()
        self.map.save(data, close_file=False)
        # Display the map in the WebEngineView 
        self.map_view.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())
        data.close()

    def update_location(self) -> None:
        """Update the map's location and heading based on user input."""
        try:
            latitude = float(self.lat_input.text())
            longitude = float(self.lon_input.text())
            heading = float(self.heading_input.text())
            self.create_map(latitude, longitude, heading, [])
        except ValueError:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(self,
                 "Error", "Invalid latitude, longitude, or heading")

    def update_frame_style(self) -> None:
        """Update the frame style based on the `triggered` variable."""
        red = "border: 5px solid red; border-radius: 155px;"
        black = "border: 5px solid black; border-radius: 155px;"
        if self.triggered:
            # create a loop to blink the frame in parallel
            self.timer = QTimer()
            self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_frame_style)
            self.timer.start(1000)
            if self.frame.styleSheet() == red:
                self.frame.setStyleSheet(black)
            else:
                self.frame.setStyleSheet(red)
        else:
            # reset the frame to black
            self.frame.setStyleSheet(black)

    def trigger_frame(self) -> None:
        """Toggle the frame color based on an external trigger."""
        self.triggered = not self.triggered
        self.update_frame_style()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Dynamic Location Update with Heading")
        self.resize(600, 600)
        self.setCentralWidget(Map())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Map()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


Thank you.
EDIT: I solved with javascript. If anyone wonder I can share.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Unrelated: avoid to constantly create QTimers as local references, especially if you don't plan on retriggering them based on a condition (self.timer will keep calling update_frame_style even if self.triggered is False). Either use QTimer.singleShot(), or just create a persistent timer and start/stop it when necessary.

@musicamante Thank you for tip, I wanted to create a flashing on frame so I keep calling update_frame_style while triggered. I might move the creating self.timer inside init function. But I don't agree with  (self.timer will keep calling update_frame_style even if self.triggered is False) this statement.

@musicamante Well, now I understand the idea of using QTimer.singleShot(). I take back my disagreement. Thank you.
